# Usage fees / royalties for re-purposing an existing illustration

Tags: illustration, business, client-relations

a client paid me a fair fee to be allowed to use an existing illustration I had done as a background image on their website.

Now they have contacted me to ask whether they could print the high-resolution version of that same illustration in a large-format reproduction to hang on their office wall.

Aside from any production / framing costs, how should I go about calculating a fair fee for the usage?

What are some considerations? Are there any pricing resources out there that could help determine a reasonable price?

(cross-posted to [DeviantArt](http://forum.deviantart.com/art/general/2072409/))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question only depends on what you think your work is worth and is different for every person you ask.

Personally if the client was a good client and paid you a fair fee and all they want to do is print it for personal usage in the office I would allow them one print for free and disclose that in a written format and send them a PDF to be e-signed.  If they are going to print it for distribution that is a different matter.  Nit-picking clients wanting to show-off work they paid for to me is greedy and not necessary if there is no gain on investment for them and you should look at it like free exposure.  If they are wanting it to be printed instead of charging them tell them you need to include a watermark with a link to a site or something which relates to free advertising.

Typically the price is figured by the quantity to be printed.  Since they appear to be only wanting one and if you want a calculation then calculate the total hours it took you for the work, total canvas size, then divide and multiply the amount by the square footage.  If they are asking you to re-do the illustration for print then charge by the hours it takes you.

Comment: Appreciate the opinions. I agree that there is certainly a self-promotion aspect to consider in this case.

Answer (score 2):

A fair fee is one you're willing to accept and one they're willing to give you.

But there can be other variables involved. The big one is whether or not this is an exclusive license. If they are asking to do this but don't want anyone else to be able to do it, then you need to charge much more as it's prohibiting you from selling a license to others. On the other hand, if they're just asking for one copy, and don't care if you make 1000 more, then you can perhaps treat it more as commodity pricing.

Comment: Thanks for bringing exclusivity into the discussion. Very helpful consideration!